# Change CSS visibilty property using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and I'm having an issue using it to remove a CSS property.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to have a text input box invisible when a checkbox is unchecked, and make it visible when the box is checked.  Here is the code I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>


if (document.box.test.checked == true)
    {document.getElementById("test").style.display == "";
    }



</script>
<body>

<form name="box"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="engraved">Engraved?
</form>

<div id="test" style="display:none">
<p>Engraving Message here:</p>
<form>
<input type="text" name="engraving-text" value="Type here">
</form>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: Note that there's a difference between the [`visibility` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/visibility) and the [`display` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onchange` event on the `checkbox`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="engraved" onchange="show_hide()">
```

and then toggle the input box

```
function show_hide()
{
    if (document.box.test.checked) {
        document.getElementById("test").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("test").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYU3y/) for testing

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems here.

1. the script you wrote changes the display to "" which will still show
   the text box it should be `display="none";`
2. the script will not run every time a person changes the value of the check-box.

try this.
Encapsulate your check into a function and then add the function to the body onload event and the checkbox's oncchage event.

```
<script>

function checkHideTextField()
{
   if (document.box.test.checked == true)
   {
      document.getElementById("test").style.display == "none";
   }
}

</script>
<body onload="checkHideTextField()">

<form name="box"> 
<input onchage="checkHideTextField()" type="checkbox" name="test" value="engraved">Engraved?
</form>

<div id="test" style="display:none">
<p>Engraving Message here:</p>
<form>
<input type="text" name="engraving-text" value="Type here">
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```